# UserDefaults recovers deleted item in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

my question about deleted items, if I delete item and stop simulator Immediately then run again, sometimes the UserDefaults recovers that deleted item. how to solve that?

my code:

```
struct ExpenseItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let amount: Double
}

class Expenses: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [ExpenseItem]() {
        
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            
            if let encode = try? encoder.encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encode, forKey: "itemsData")
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "itemsData") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                items = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }
        
        items = []
    }
    
}
```

I think that issue is normaly, but I hope to get solution for that.

Comment: Don't *stop simulator Immediately*, this is pretty far from reality. The UserDefaults database is updated periodically but not instantly.

Comment: The easiest way to ensure a proper sync of UserDefaults in my experience is to minimize the app to background, then wait a few seconds and finally kill the app from Xcode.

Comment: Why not just quit the app normally? No waiting.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) which says, “When you set a default value, it’s changed synchronously within your process, and asynchronously to persistent storage and other processes.” And if you force-quit the app before that write to persistent storage is done, it can be lost. Either `synchronize` or store your critical model data somewhere other than the user defaults system that has this asychronous writing pattern.

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults performs in an asynchronous way. So there are chances that the changes you perform may not instantly reflect in the app.

So you can try either of the two approaches given below:

1. Use main thread to perform the saving and deletions with UserDefaults.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                if let encode = try? encoder.encode(self.items) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(encode, forKey: "itemsData")
                }
            }
```

2. Use the synchronize() method of userDefaults

```
    didSet {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encode = try? encoder.encode(self.items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encode, forKey: "itemsData")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() // Explicitly synchronize data
        }
    }
```